# How to add a legend to an Argand Diagram with several items in python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I got an array with complex numbers like:

`a = np.array([0.074-0.046j], [-0.005+0.091j], [0.039-0.023j], [-0.245+0.015j], [0.642-0.766j])`

With the function "polarplot" I am able to plot the array "a":

```
def polarplot(a):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
for x in a:
    plt.polar([np.angle(x)],[np.abs(x)],marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Then I got this result:
[Argand Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6p4O.png)

When I try to add an legend with `plt.legend(loc="lower right")` nothing appears. How can i add a legend to this plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to add a `label = ''` when you call `plt.polar()`

So your code should look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.074-0.046j], [-0.005+0.091j], [0.039-0.023j], [-0.245+0.015j], [0.642-0.766j]])
def polarplot(a):    
    for x in a:
        plt.polar([np.angle(x)],[np.abs(x)],marker='o',label = '%s' %x)
    plt.legend(loc = "lower right")
    plt.show()

polarplot(a)
```

This gives the image shown below:

[image]

Note that you will probably want to move the legend and change the labels when actually implementing this.

Comment: Thank you David. That is the solution. I edited the `plt.legend()` section like `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)` and it works perfect!

Comment: Your welcome :) As that was what you were looking for then please 'accept' the answer.